# Gumby Framework Installation

Tags: html, css, frameworks, installation, responsive-design

I'm just starting to learn a Responsive CSS Framework, so I would like to compare Foundation 4, Gumby and Bootstrap by myself.

I could run Foundation 4 and Bootstrap, but Gumby doesn't work.

I include the files of the framework and the web doesn't stop loading. I tried deleting some lines, and the problem is including the gumby.css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gumby.css">
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        asd
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/gumby.min.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is probably that I've been including the wrong files, is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what your problem is. You need to run this on a live web server, or set the `//` hrefs to `http://` within index.html and css/gumby.css otherwise it takes forever for the jquery/custom font http requests to time out, and the fallback to local versions to happen.

EDIT: I see you've removed a lot of the lines of code from Gumby's default template files. I would use them, else you're going to get huge amount of inconsistencies across browsers. This is the code I use:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Gumby - A Flexible, Responsive CSS Framework - Powered by SASS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="humans.txt">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gumby.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



    <script>
    var oldieCheck = Boolean(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.match(/\soldie\s/g));
    if(!oldieCheck) {
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    } else {
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    if(!window.jQuery) {
    if(!oldieCheck) {
      document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"><\/script>');
    } else {
      document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
    }
    </script>

    <script src="js/libs/gumby.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
    window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UAXXXXXXXX1'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
    Modernizr.load({
      load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
    });
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
    <![endif]-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving modernizr to the head of the document, and the jquery above the the main and gumby.js files

I'm not really sure what you mean by "the web doesn't stop loading", but I assume it has something to do with the JS being blocked.

You're probably also going to want to have the following in the head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you download and extract the files, take a look into the **demo.html** file in the main folder, there you have a complete example of the included css and main js libraries, some validations for IE issues and also commented js modules that can be added.